# How do I call a method on a specific base class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

How do I call a method on a specific base class? I know that I can use `super(C, self)` in the below example to get automatic method resolution - but I want to be able to specify which base class's method I am calling?

```
class A(object):
    def test(self):
        print 'A'

class B(object):
    def test(self):
        print 'B'

class C(A,B):
    def test(self):
        print 'C'
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to know how to do this for the `C` class?  Do you want to differentiate at runtime, on an instance?  Can you show how you want to use this functionality?

Comment: @SethMMorton: Well the others don't have any base classes to call

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  I was prompting for more details on what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just name the "base class".

If you wanted to call say `B.test` from your `C` class:

```
class C(A,B):
    def test(self):
        B.test(self)
```

**Example:**

```
class A(object):

    def test(self):
        print 'A'


class B(object):

    def test(self):
        print 'B'


class C(A, B):

    def test(self):
        B.test(self)


c = C()
c.test()
```

**Output:**

```
$ python -i foo.py
B
>>>
```

See: [Python Classes (Tutorial)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)